# Add authentication to wsdl service in Genexus

Tags: genexus

I'm studying how to create a web service with Genexus 17U10. The first part looks very simple, following this https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?4210,Web+Services+with+GeneXus I can expose the service and consume it in another project. Now I want to add some kind of authorization but I can't find how to set it. Does genexus manage it somehow? I can't find informations about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier and recommended to use REST services and authenticate using GAM.
For SOAP services you have to add extra programming.